# Jquery AJAX get from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this php and js file

PHP

```
<?php
    $user_id = '10';
    echo $user_id;
?>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:"uid.php",
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
}
});
});
```

I get "10" as alert

However for this PHP and JS there is **no alert**

PHP

```
<?php
class uidclass{
function uid_func($event, $arguments)
{
    $user_id = '10';
    echo $user_id;
}
}
?>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:"uid.php",
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
}
});
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you create an object and called the function?

Comment: what happens when you call the PHP directly in the browser ? Most probably nothing with that code only... so that's exactly waht your AJAX "reads": nothing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the class and method properly

```
<?php
class uidclass{
    function uid_func($event, $arguments) {
        $user_id = '10';
        echo $user_id;
    }
}

$bob = new uidclass;
$bob->uid_func(null,null); // since the parameters are not defined
```

or like this

```
<?php
class uidclass{
    function uid_func($event = null, $arguments = null) {
        $user_id = '10';
        return $user_id;
    }
}

$bob = new uidclass;
print $bob->uid_func(); // we have already set defaults in the function definition
```

or even add a constructor and print inside the method

```
<?php
class uidclass{
    public function uid_func($event = null, $arguments = null) {
        $user_id = '10';
        print $user_id;
    }
    public function __construct() {
        $this->uid_func();
    }
}

$bob = new uidclass();
```